# Facebook App Requests are not compelling to invitations to users - whats your usage pattern?

Tags: facebook, apprequests

Using the Facebook app requests dialog means I can send an invite to a user.  Usually this invite will appear in their notifications menu at the top of their Facebook page.  And I will see:

"Mike Hogan sent you a request in FooApp"

Which is not at all compelling to a user.  If they click on this notification, it takes them to the front page of FooApp, without much context of what the invite is.  I'm experiencing about 85% tail-off of my App Requests done this way.  Understandably.

Users do get a chance to see more detail of the request if they click to view all their App Requests, but who does that?

I have received requests from other apps that appear in my top Notifications menu, along with a red diamond, that when clicked on, take me to the App Requests page, instead of directly to the app.  This allows me see more context of the request, instead of being hurled in ignorance at the app's front page ;-)  This might work better, but I have no idea how to make that happen - how to make clicking on an app request in the notifications go the the App Requests page instead of to FooApp.

So I am wondering how people get App Requests to work for them?

Any and all ideas much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

"Requests that are Invites (the recipient user has not installed the app) do not display the message parameter and are categorized differently in the Apps and Games Dashboard.".

So people who have not installed your app get a less inviting message.  The best option in this case, as far as I can see, is to do what jBit recommended and display as much context as you can when a user lands on your app with a request_id in the url.

For users who have installed the app, they get to see the more detailed message.

Answer (score 0):

To get the users from the *"Mike Hogan sent you a request in FooApp"* to the App Request page I have my application detect urls with variables `ref=notif` and `notif_t=app_request` and then do a redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/?sk=apps`.

I also keep track of the generated request ids and I use them to guide the user to relevant content.

But if anybody has any better suggestions I would also like to hear them.

Comment: Thanks jBit.  I might do this as an intermediate step.  But some apps, like Flixster, link directly to https://www.facebook.com/?sk=apps in their notification entries.  Is this just the privilege of hosted apps?

Comment: I think the old style FBML request form will do this - the FB.ui apprequest is supposed to do this but do not.

Comment: Just to come back and add a bit more to this, I've not stopped worrying about https://www.facebook.com/?sk=apps :-)  When a user comes to my app with ref=notif set, I just display a page with my own invitation context, for each of the request_ids in the URL.  It works a charm.