# Facebook canvas app - delete invite after accept

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing a Facebook iframe/canvas app on fanpage as a new tab and given the ability to users to invite friends. However when their friends accepted the invitation, the invitation doesn't delete and still exist in the applications request.

As far as I know we need to get from`$_REQUEST["request_ids"]` but things happen when users accept the invitation, it went to the apps before redirect to fanpage. So suppose `$_REQUEST["request_ids"]` shown in the apps but once it redirect, the `$_REQUEST["request_ids"]` gone !

What should I do ?

Comment: Relevant: [Facebook App Requests ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909231/facebook-app-requests-are-not-compelling-to-invitations-to-users-whats-your-usa/6910348)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 (or more) ways to do what u want:
- deleting the app request before doing the redirect
- append the request_ids field in the redirect url

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the Question, you have to manually delete the app request similar to below:

```
$facebook->api('/'.$requistid.'?access_token='.$access_token,'DELETE');
```

$requistid is the request id you need to delete.

You can get all the app requests by doin this graph api call:

```
$facebook->api('/me/apprequests?fields=id,from&access_token='.$access_token);
```